# Raspberry Pi and Pressure Sensor / Pressure Switch

Tags: gpio, sensor

I have to create simple device for a promotion campaign.

I should react when someone seats on the chair therefore I need advice on choosing the right sensor.

Should it be pressure sensor and what kind is better for Raspberry Pi?

I was suggested to use pressure switch at Electrical Engineering Stackexchange. Can someone give me some help on which switch to use and how to connect it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [force sensing resistor](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9375). If you look at the datasheet, there is a circuit for connecting the force sensing resistor as a threshold switch. You can design the circuit according to the example provided in the datasheet and set a threshold weight/load to trigger a signal. You can connect the output of the opamp to the Raspberry Pi. You must remember that the GPIO signals are at 3.3V level.

Comment: So, if there are 100 chairs, so 100 sensor will be used, but how to integrate 100 sensors with pi, or for per sensor there will be 1 pi?

Comment: There are I2C based GPIO expanders. You could connect all your sensors to the expander and interface it to the Pi via the I2C interface.